# Need to fetch n percentage of rows in u-sql query

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Need help in writing u-sql query to fetch me top n percentage of rows.I have one dataset from which need to take total count of rows and take top 3% rows from dataset based on col1. Code which I have written is :

```
 @count = SELECT Convert.ToInt32(COUNT(*)) AS cnt FROM @telData;
@count1=SELECT cnt/100 AS cnt1 FROM @count;
DECLARE @cnt int=SELECT Convert.ToInt32(cnt1*3)  FROM @count1;


        @EngineFailureData=
            SELECT vin,accelerator_pedal_position,enginefailure=1
            FROM @telData
            ORDER BY accelerator_pedal_position DESC
            FETCH @cnt ROWS;
```

@telData is my basic dataset.Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments first:

1. `FETCH` currently only takes literals as arguments (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt621321.aspx)
2. `@var = SELECT ...` will assign the name `@var` to the rowset expression that starts with the `SELECT`. U-SQL (currently) does not provide you with stateful scalar variable assignment from query results. Instead you would use a `CROSS JOIN` or other `JOIN` to join the scalar value in.

Now to the solution:

To get the percentage, take a look at the `ROW_NUMBER()` and `PERCENT_RANK()` functions. For example, the following shows you how to use either to answer your question. Given the simpler code for `PERCENT_RANK()` (no need for the `MAX()` and `CROSS JOIN`), I would suggest that solution.

```
DECLARE @percentage double = 0.25; // 25%

@data = SELECT * 
        FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20) 
             ) AS T(pos);

@data =
SELECT PERCENT_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY pos) AS p_rank,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY pos) AS r_no,
       pos
FROM @data;

@cut_off =
SELECT ((double) MAX(r_no)) * (1.0 - @percentage) AS max_r
FROM @data;

@r1 =
SELECT *
FROM @data CROSS JOIN @cut_off
WHERE ((double) r_no) > max_r;

@r2 =
SELECT *
FROM @data
WHERE p_rank >= 1.0 - @percentage;

OUTPUT @r1
TO "/output/top_perc1.csv"
ORDER BY p_rank DESC
USING Outputters.Csv();

OUTPUT @r2
TO "/output/top_perc2.csv"
ORDER BY p_rank DESC
USING Outputters.Csv();
```